# Idiomatic append operation

Tags: rust, idioms

I'm writing a function that will transfer the contents from one `Vec` to another.

I managed to write two different versions of the same code. One is cleaner, but is potentially slower.

Version 1:

```
fn move_values<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    loop {
        let value = buffer.pop();
        if value.is_none() {
            return;
        }
        recipient.push(value.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
fn move_values<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    for value in buffer.iter() {
        recipient.push(value.clone());
    }

    buffer.clear();
}
```

My initial gut feeling is that Version 1 is faster because it only requires a single run through the buffer; while Version 2 is more "Rusty" because it involves iterating over a collection rather than using `loop`.

Which of these is more idiomatic or "better practice" in general?

Note, I'm aware of `append`, I'm trying to do this by hand for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. There's a built-in operation for this, [`Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append):

> Moves all the elements of other into `Self`, leaving other empty.

```
fn move_values<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    recipient.append(buffer);
}
```

---

Neither of your functions even compile:

```
fn move_values_1<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    loop {
        let value = buffer.pop();
        if value.is_none() {
            return;
        }
        recipient.push_front(card.unwrap());
    }
}
```

```
error[E0425]: unresolved name `card`
 --> src/main.rs:7:30
  |
7 |         recipient.push_front(card.unwrap());
  |                              ^^^^ unresolved name
```

```
fn move_values_2<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    for value in buffer.iter() {
        recipient.push_front(value.clone());
    }

    buffer.clear();
}
```

```
error: no method named `push_front` found for type `&mut std::vec::Vec<T>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |         recipient.push_front(card.unwrap());
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

> if I were to implement it myself

Well, there's a reason that it's implemented for you, but sure... let's dig in.

Checking if something `is_some` or `is_none` can usually be avoided by pattern matching. For example:

```
fn move_values_1<T>(buffer: &mut Vec<T>, recipient: &mut Vec<T>) {
    while let Some(v) = buffer.pop() {
        recipient.push(v);
    }
}
```

Of course, this moves everything in **reverse order** because pushing and popping to a Vec both occur at the end.

Calling `clone` doesn't do what you want unless your trait bounds say that `T` implements `Clone`. Otherwise, you are just cloning the *reference* itself.

You can avoid the need for cloning if you drain the values from one collection and insert them into the other:

```
for value in buffer.drain(..) {
    recipient.push(value);
}
```

But that `for` loop is silly, just `extend` the collection using the iterator:

```
recipient.extend(buffer.drain(..));
```

I'd **still** use the built in `append` method to do this when transferring between collections of the same type, as it is probably optimized for the precise data layout, and potentially specialized for certain types of data.

Comment: Changed the question to more closely resemble the real problem

Comment: I'm changing the question back to the way it was so your answer remains relevant, just warning you ahead of time in case you're editing the answer

Comment: @ElectricCoffee sounds good. I believe the answer you are looking for is still in this answer - the last code block, specifically.

Comment: Done, I changed the `push_front` bit to `push` since it's a left-over from the copy-pasted `VecDeque` code that I missed when converting it to `Vec`. If you could be so kind as to remove the compiler errors, that would be splendid :)